# How to deal with NaN values in data in Python?

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, missing-data

I have a large data set containing many NaN values in multiple columns.

I have tried the following code but it is not dropping Nan value from the data set

```
df = pd.read_excel('sec3_data.xlsx')
df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"])
df['Deviation from Partisanship'].unique()
```

Output:

```
array([nan, 'Vote for opposing party', 'Vote for own party'], dtype=object)
```

It clearly shows there is still some nan values available. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write it as,

```
df = df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"])
```

or,

```
df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either reassign to a new dataframe:

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"])
```

Or perform the drop `inplace`:

```
df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"], inplace=True)
```

You can find more info in the docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Answer (score 0):

```
# Method 1
df = pd.read_excel('sec3_data.xlsx')
df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"], inplace=True)
df['Deviation from Partisanship'].unique()

# Method 2
df = pd.read_excel('sec3_data.xlsx')
df2 = df.dropna(subset=["Deviation from Partisanship"])
df2['Deviation from Partisanship'].unique()
```